# Node fibers error while running RocketChat self hosted on M1 Mac

Tags: meteor, node-modules, apple-silicon, fibers, node-fibers

Setup Reference
https://developer.rocket.chat/open-source-projects/server/server-environment-setup/mac-osx

Error screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0MT7.png)

I am trying to setup RocketChat v6 on a local M1 MacBook Air. The `yarn dev` should ideally start the dev server, however it is giving me errors as described above.

Node version: v14.21.3 |
Meteor version: v2.12 |
Device: MacBook Air M1 Chip

Answer (score 0):

Run `yarn add node-gyp` and after `yarn dev`.
It will help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).